# Where is a good repository or resource for a lot of diverse sample equations?

Tags: equations, documentation, repositories, resources

Backstory:

I am building a LaTeX to Speech library, and require a large amount of diverse samples which are readily available. Right now, I am trying to fish for examples out of tutorials and this website, but this takes up a large amount of time, and may still not be the most diverse, as I will be getting the "Hello World" examples over and over again.

So where can I find a large assortment of diverse equations which do not require me to fish through documentation or tutorials?

Answer (score 6):

the file `testmath.tex` is part of the documentation for the `amsmath` package.  it's in tex live, on ctan, or available via a link on the page
http://www.ams.org/tex/amslatex (under "additional documentation}.

the content is kind of "random", but has a good variety of examples and has been used, among other things, for stress testing of new math fonts.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a useful collection of latex examples: [Latex-examples](https://github.com/MartinThoma/LaTeX-examples)

Comment: ... Now I just need a useful grep command to fish out the equations recursively.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend searching for some open source math books; there are quite some on Github, and probably more elsewhere. That way, you can somehow choose the kind of formulae you want to test; eg., [topology](https://github.com/vporton/algebraic-general-topology) (with much algebra), [mathematical modelling](https://github.com/WarrenWeckesser/math-modelling-book) (linear algebra, differential equations), [combinatorics](https://github.com/jasongrout/BogartCombinatorics), or much more abstract stuff like the [HoTT book](https://github.com/HoTT/book) with a lot of diagrams.

There's some filtering to be done, but I'm sure there's a lot of interesting (and big) enough projects out there.